# Performance Issue:_JSP service taking long time to respond

Tags: performance, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets, weblogic11g

While debugging performance issue using DynaTrace,I have observed that my application is taking much time in _JSP Service.What does that mean?How to fix it?

Note: If we restart application the actual response time is 8secs,but if 15 users are using in parallel ,gradually application performance in degrading its taking 115secs on average.Using weblogic server 11g,Attached the [dynatrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNPIG.jpg) image

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please read [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: The snapshot do not show any long time running JSP...